# MySQLで真偽値を格納する場合、bit(1)型のフィールドよりtinyint(1)型の方が良い？

Tags: mysql

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・MySQL5.7に真偽値を格納したい

**知りたいこと**
・boolean型、bit(1)型、tinyint(1)型の何れが良い？

---

**Q1.boolean リテラルについて**
・[TRUE および FALSE 定数はそれぞれ 1 と 0 として評価される](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/boolean-literals.html)、と書かれていますが、これはどのようなデータ型に対しても当てはまるのでしょうか？
・例えば、tinyint(1)型に格納された1だけではなく、bit(1)型に格納された1に対しても、SELECTする際「where フィールド名 = true」は成立する？

---

**Q2.boolean型は、tinyint(1)型と完全に同一？**
・boolean型でフィールド作成するとtinyint(1)型で作成されるのですが、これは、最初からtinyint(1)型を指定して作成したフィールト内容と全く同じということを意味するのでしょうか？

---

**Q3.boolean型は、どうしてbit(1)型ではない？**
・tinyint(1)型だと01以外も格納されることが有り得るので、0と1しか格納できないbit(1)型の方が、より適切と思うのですが…
・boolean型を、tinyint(1)型として処理するような仕様になっているのは、何か理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答はあるので"Q3"については[本家SOでの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488811/tinyint-vs-bit)をみると良いかもしれません。動作はするので特に理由がなければ最終的には好みだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

1. MySQL ではリテラルとしての TRUE, FALSE は構文解析時に 1, 0 として扱われます。そのため 1, 0 と指定するのとまったく同じです。
2. 型としての BOOLEAN も同様に構文解析時に TINYINT(1) として扱われます。BOOLEAN と TINYINT(1) はまったく同じです。
3. これについてはわかりません。